# Javascript Await Changes Local Variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, port

Anyone able to explain what I'm doing wrong with my use of asynchronous functions in Javascript?

Basically, I must use an asynchronous in my Node.js code to grab an open port for me to use. There is a local variable that is being set outside of the asynchronous call that I can access/use just fine until I await for the asynchronous function to return. After that, the local variable is undefined.

```
(async () => {
    console.log("CHECK AFTER ASYNC1: " + csvFilePath);
    // First, grab a valid open port
    var port;
    while (!port || portsInProcess.indexOf(port) >= 0) {
        console.log("CHECK AFTER ASYNC2: " + csvFilePath);
        port = await getPort();
        console.log(port);
    }
    console.log("CHECK AFTER ASYNC3: " + csvFilePath);
    portsInProcess.push(port);
    // ... more code below...
```

Checks #1 and 2 are fine for the csvFilePath variable, but check #3 shows that it's undefined. The port number, however, is fine. This leads me to believe that there's some weirdness with asynchronous function calls in Javascript that ONLY affects local variables; the global variables I use further down are just fine. Unfortunately here, I cannot make the csvFilePath variable global since that will introduce race conditions on that variable too (which I'm preventing elsewhere; the while loop is to help prevent race conditions on the port number, which is basically unused in my simple tests on localhost).

Just in case it's helpful, here's the output I'm getting:

```
CHECK AFTER ASYNC1: data/text/crescent_topics.csv
CHECK AFTER ASYNC2: data/text/crescent_topics.csv
58562
CHECK AFTER ASYNC3: null
```

It might also be worth mentioning it's really only those first few lines of code to dynamically grab an open port that are the lines of code I added. The code that I had before which used a fixed port number worked just fine (including this csvFilePath variable remaining stable).

My understanding of the `await` functionality was that it makes the asynchronous function act more or less synchronously, which is what seems to be happening here; the code I have farther down that uses the port number is not running until after the port number is set. (But even if that wasn't the case, why is the csvFilePath variable being unset since I'm not altering it or using it in any way here?)

**EDIT:** Here's some more code to provide additional context

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var fs = require("fs");
var async = require('async');
var zmq = require('zmq');
var readline = require('readline');
const getPort = require('get-port');

/* Export the Nebula class */
module.exports = Nebula;

/* Location of the data for the Crescent dataset */
var textDataPath = "data/text/";
var crescentRawDataPath = textDataPath + "crescent_raw";
var crescentTFIDF = textDataPath + "crescent tfidf.csv";
var crescentTopicModel = textDataPath + "crescent_topics.csv";

/* Location of the data for the UK Health dataset */
var ukHealthRawDataPath = textDataPath + "uk_health_raw";
var ukHealthTFIDF = textDataPath + "uk_health.csv";

/* Map CSV files for text data to raw text location */
var textRawDataMappings = {};
textRawDataMappings[crescentTFIDF] = crescentRawDataPath;
textRawDataMappings[crescentTopicModel] = crescentRawDataPath;
textRawDataMappings[ukHealthTFIDF] = ukHealthRawDataPath;
textRawDataMappings[textDataPath + "uk_health_sm.csv"] = ukHealthRawDataPath;

/* The pipelines available to use */
var flatTextUIs = ["cosmos", "composite", "sirius", "centaurus"];
var pipelines = {
    andromeda: { 
        file: "pipelines/andromeda.py",
        defaultData: "data/highD/Animal_Data_study.csv"
     },
     cosmos: {
        file: "pipelines/cosmos.py",
        defaultData: textDataPath + "crescent tfidf.csv"
     },
     sirius: {
        file: "pipelines/sirius.py",
        defaultData: "data/highD/Animal_Data_paper.csv"
     },
     centaurus: {
        file: "pipelines/centaurus.py",
        defaultData: "data/highD/Animal_Data_paper.csv"
     },
     twitter: {
        file: "pipelines/twitter.py",
     },
     composite: {
        file: "pipelines/composite.py",
        defaultData: textDataPath + "crescent tfidf.csv"
     },
     elasticsearch: {
        file: "pipelines/espipeline.py",
        args: []
     }
};

/* The locations of the different types of datasets on the server */
var textDataFolder = "data/text/";
var highDDataFolder = "data/highD/";
var customCSVFolder = "data/customCSV/";

var sirius_prototype = 2;

// An array to track the ports being processed to eliminate race conditions
// as much as possible
var portsInProcess = [];

var nextSessionNumber = 0;
var usedSessionNumbers = [];

/* Nebula class constructor */
function Nebula(io, pipelineAddr) {
    /* This allows you to use "Nebula(obj)" as well as "new Nebula(obj)" */
    if (!(this instanceof Nebula)) { 
        return new Nebula(io);
    }

    /* The group of rooms currently active, each with a string identifier
     * Each room represents an instance of a visualization that can be shared
     * among clients.
     */
    this.rooms = {};
    this.io = io;

    /* For proper use in callback functions */
    var self = this;

    /* Accept new WebSocket clients */
    io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    // Skipped some irrelevant Socket.io callbacks

    **// Use the csvFilePath to store the name of a user-defined CSV file
        var csvFilePath = null;**

        /* Helper function to tell the client that the CSV file is now ready for them
        * to use. They are also sent a copy of the data
        */
        var csvFileReady = function(csvFilePath) {

            // Let the client know that the CSV file is now ready to be used on
            // the server
            socket.emit("csvDataReady");

            // Prepare to parse the CSV file
            var csvData = [];
            const rl = readline.createInterface({
                input: fs.createReadStream(csvFilePath),
                crlfDelay: Infinity
            });

            // Print any error messages we encounter
            rl.on('error', function (err) {
                console.log("Error while parsing CSV file: " + csvFilePath);
                console.log(err);
            });

            // Read each line of the CSV file one at a time and parse it
            var columnHeaders = [];
            var firstColumnName;
            rl.on('line', function (data) {                
                var dataColumns = data.split(",");

                // If we haven't saved any column names yet, do so first
                if (columnHeaders.length == 0) {
                    columnHeaders = dataColumns;
                    firstColumnName = columnHeaders[0];
                }

                // Process each individual line of data in the CSV file
                else {
                    var dataObj = {};
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < dataColumns.length; i++) {
                        var key = columnHeaders[i];
                        var value = dataColumns[i];
                        dataObj[key] = value
                    }
                    csvData.push(dataObj);
                }

            });

            // All lines are read, file is closed now.
            rl.on('close', function () {

                // On certain OSs, like Windows, an extra, blank line may be read
                // Check for this and remove it if it exists
                var lastObservation = csvData[csvData.length-1];
                var lastObservationKeys = Object.keys(lastObservation);
                if (lastObservationKeys.length = 1 && lastObservation[lastObservationKeys[0]] == "") {
                    csvData.pop();
                }

                // Provide the CSV data to the client
                socket.emit("csvDataReadComplete", csvData, firstColumnName);
            });
        };

        **/* Allows the client to specify a CSV file already on the server to use */
        socket.on("setCSV", function(csvName) {
            console.log("setCSV CALLED");
            csvFilePath = "data/" + csvName;
            csvFileReady(csvFilePath);
            console.log("CSV FILE SET: " + csvFilePath);
        });**

        // Skipped some more irrelevant callbacks

        /*  a client/ a room. If the room doesn't next exist yet,
        * initiate it and send the new room to the client. Otherwise, send
        * the client the current state of the room.
        */
        socket.on('join', function(roomName, user, pipeline, args) {
            console.log("Join called for " + pipeline + " pipeline; room " + roomName);
            socket.roomName = roomName;
            socket.user = user;
            socket.join(roomName);

            console.log("CSV FILE PATH: " + csvFilePath);

            var pipelineArgsCopy = [];

            if (!self.rooms[roomName]) {
                var room = {};
                room.name = roomName;
                room.count = 1;
                room.points = new Map();
                room.similarity_weights = new Map();

                if (pipeline == "sirius" || pipeline == "centaurus") {
                    room.attribute_points = new Map();
                    room.attribute_similarity_weights = new Map();
                    room.observation_data = [];
                    room.attribute_data = [];
                }

                /* Create a pipeline client for this room */
                console.log("CHECK BEFORE ASYNC: " + csvFilePath);
                **// Here's the code snippet I provided above**
                **(async () => {
                    console.log("CHECK AFTER ASYNC1: " + csvFilePath);
                    // First, grab a valid open port
                    var port;
                    while (!port || portsInProcess.indexOf(port) >= 0) {
                        console.log("CHECK AFTER ASYNC2: " + csvFilePath);
                        port = await getPort();
                        console.log(port);
                    }
                    console.log("CHECK AFTER ASYNC3: " + csvFilePath);**
                    portsInProcess.push(port);
                    console.log("CHECK AFTER ASYNC4: " + csvFilePath);

                    if (!pipelineAddr) {
                        var pythonArgs = ["-u"];
                        if (pipeline in pipelines) {

                            // A CSV file path should have already been set. This
                            // file path should be used to indicate where to find
                            // the desired file
                            console.log("LAST CHECK: " + csvFilePath);
                            if (!csvFilePath) {
                                csvFilePath = pipelines[pipeline].defaultData;
                            }
                            console.log("FINAL CSV FILE: " + csvFilePath);
                            pipelineArgsCopy.push(csvFilePath);

                            // If the UI supports reading flat text files, tell the
                            // pipeline where to find the files
                            if (flatTextUIs.indexOf(pipeline) >= 0) {
                                pipelineArgsCopy.push(textRawDataMappings[csvFilePath]);
                            }

                            // Set the remaining pipeline args
                            pythonArgs.push(pipelines[pipeline].file);
                            pythonArgs.push(port.toString());
                            if (pipeline != "twitter" && pipeline != "elasticsearch") {
                                pythonArgs = pythonArgs.concat(pipelineArgsCopy);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            pythonArgs.push(pipelines.cosmos.file);
                            pythonArgs.push(port.toString());
                            pythonArgs.push(pipelines.cosmos.defaultData);
                            pythonArgs.push(crescentRawDataPath);
                        }

                        // used in case of CosmosRadar
                        for (var key in args) {
                            if (args.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                pythonArgs.push("--" + key);
                                pythonArgs.push(args[key]);
                            }
                        }

                        // Dynamically determine which distance function should be
                        // used
                        if (pythonArgs.indexOf("--dist_func") < 0) {
                            if (pipeline === "twitter" || pipeline === "elasticsearch" ||
                                    csvFilePath.startsWith(textDataPath)) {
                                pythonArgs.push("--dist_func", "cosine");
                            }
                            else {
                                pythonArgs.push("--dist_func", "euclidean");
                            }
                        }

                        console.log(pythonArgs);
                        console.log("");

                        var pipelineInstance = spawn("python2.7", pythonArgs, {stdout: "inherit"});

                        pipelineInstance.on("error", function(err) {
                            console.log("python2.7.exe not found. Trying python.exe");
                            pipelineInstance = spawn("python", pythonArgs,{stdout: "inherit"});

                            pipelineInstance.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
                                console.log("Pipeline: " + data.toString());
                            });
                            pipelineInstance.stderr.on("data", function(data) {
                                console.log("Pipeline error: " + data.toString());
                            });
                        });

                        /* Data received by node app from python process, 
                         * ouptut this data to output stream(on 'data'), 
                         * we want to convert that received data into a string and 
                         * append it to the overall data String
                         */
                        pipelineInstance.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
                            console.log("Pipeline STDOUT: " + data.toString());
                        });
                        pipelineInstance.stderr.on("data", function(data) {
                            console.log("Pipeline error: " + data.toString());
                        });

                        room.pipelineInstance = pipelineInstance;
                    }

                    /* Connect to the pipeline */
                    pipelineAddr = pipelineAddr || "tcp://127.0.0.1:" + port.toString();

                    room.pipelineSocket = zmq.socket('pair');
                    room.pipelineSocket.connect(pipelineAddr);

                    pipelineAddr = null;
                    portsInProcess.splice(portsInProcess.indexOf(port), 1);

                    /* Listens for messages from the pipeline */
                    room.pipelineSocket.on('message', function (msg) {
                        self.handleMessage(room, msg);
                    });

                    self.rooms[roomName] = socket.room = room;
                    invoke(room.pipelineSocket, "reset");
                })();
            }
            else {
                socket.room = self.rooms[roomName];
                socket.room.count += 1;

                if (pipeline == "sirius" || pipeline == "centaurus") {
                    socket.emit('update', sendRoom(socket.room, true), true);
                    socket.emit('update', sendRoom(socket.room, false), false);
                }
                else {
                    socket.emit('update', sendRoom(socket.room));
                }
            }

            // Reset the csvFilePath to null for future UIs...
            // I don't think this is actually necessary since 
            // csvFilePath is local to the "connections" message,
            // which is called for every individual room
            csvFilePath = null;
        });

        // Skipped the rest of the code; it's irrelevant
    });
}
```

Full printouts:

```
setCSV CALLED
CSV FILE SET: data/text/crescent_topics.csv
Join called for sirius pipeline; room sirius0
CSV FILE PATH: data/text/crescent_topics.csv
CHECK BEFORE ASYNC: data/text/crescent_topics.csv
CHECK AFTER ASYNC1: data/text/crescent_topics.csv
CHECK AFTER ASYNC2: data/text/crescent_topics.csv
58562
CHECK AFTER ASYNC3: null
CHECK AFTER ASYNC4: null
LAST CHECK: null
FINAL CSV FILE: data/highD/Animal_Data_paper.csv
[ '-u',
  'pipelines/sirius.py',
  '58562',
  'data/highD/Animal_Data_paper.csv',
  undefined,
  '--dist_func',
  'euclidean' ]
```

Since bolding of code doesn't work, just search for the "**" to find the relevant pieces I've marked.

TL;DR  There's a lot of communication happening between the client and server to establish an individualized communication that is directly linked to a specific dataset. The user has the ability to upload a custom CSV file to the system, but the code I'm working with right now is just trying to select an existing CSV file on the server, so I omitted the callbacks for the custom CSV file. Once the file has been selected, the client asks to "join" a room/session. The case I'm working with right now assumes that this is a new room/session as opposed to trying to do some shared room/session with another client. (Yes, I know, the code is messy for sharing rooms/sessions, but it works for the most part for now and is not my main concern.) Again, all this code worked just fine before the asynchronous code was added (and using a static port variable), so I don't know what changed so much by adding it.

Comment: From the code in the question, it sounds like `getPort` is reassigning `csvFilePath`, though that sounds weird - if that's not what's happening, then the code in the question is missing some things that the code in your script has. Need a [MCVE] to be sure

Comment: `cvsFilePath` is likely getting reassigned by something outside your function during the time it is `await` ing, thus messing up this function.  A simple rule is to not use shared variables that can be modified inside of asynchronous operations because while they are asynchronously doing their thing and waiting for completion something else might run and change those shared variables.  Probably you should pass them into this async function as an argument and then they won't get changed out from under you.

Comment: If you want more precise path, you need to show us more of the code so we can see where `cvsFIlePath` is defined, how it's using, what else can change it, etc...

Comment: Use const https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: Maybe cut down on all the text and show us some more relevant code, we have no clue what else is going on in context here.

Comment: it has nothing to do with `async/await`. and `await` has eliminated the race conditions here.
the problem is the scope of your variant `csvFilePath`. where did you declare it?

Comment: Sorry for there not being as much code... My node.js file is massive. There's a ton happening in there that isn't relevant to the problem at hand. I'll edit the code above to try and provide more context.

Comment: I tried adding more code for context, omitting still as much as I could since the file is almost 900 lines long... The first declaration is listed in there

Comment: @jfriend00 There isn't anything else running at the same time (or shouldn't be). I'm trying to force the code to be synchronous at that point in time. Also, if there was something else happening to alter the state of ```csvFilePath```, I'd expect to see more printouts from the client and/or server. Trying to establish an open port and spawn a Python process is the last couple of steps in generating a valid line of communication between client and server, so nothing else should be happening yet

Comment: Now that you've added the rest of your code, I can see exactly what's occurring and I explained in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you now included the whole code context, we can see that the issue is that the code after your `async` IIFE is what is causing the problem.

An `async` function returns a promise as soon as it hits an `await`.  And, while that `await` is waiting for its asynchronous operation, the code following the call to the `async` function runs.  In your case, you're essentially doing this:

```
var csvFilePath = someGoodValue;

(async () => {
     port = await getPort();
     console.log(csvFilePath);    // this will be null
})();

csvFilePath = null;               // this runs as soon as the above code hits the await
```

So, as soon as you hit your first `await`, the `async` function returns a promise and the code following it continues to run, hitting the line of code that resets your `csvFilePath`.

---

There are probably cleaner ways to restructure your code, but a simple thing you could do is this:

```
var csvFilePath = someGoodValue;

(async () => {
     port = await getPort();
     console.log(csvFilePath);    // this will be null
})().finally(() => {
    csvFilePath = null;
});
```

Note: `.finally()` is supported in node v10+.  If you're using an older version, you can reset the path in both `.then()` and `.catch()`.

Or, as your comment says, maybe you can just remove the resetting of the `csvFilePath` entirely.

Comment: I realized my mistake yesterday, but your answer provides a ton more useful detail and other ways to solve my issue than what I thought of. Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I realized after some silly tests I tried that I'm resetting `csvFilePath` to `null` outside the asynchronous call, which is what is causing the error... Oops!